# Connectivity issues after updating to Debian Jessie

Tags: networking, wifi

I have inadvertently upgraded to Debian Jessie from Debian Wheezy while I was trying to install VLC player :D.
The upgrade did not go very well as my sources.list file was mix of wheezy and Jessie(Jessie was declared stable and my sources.list was having it).
I read the manuals and tried to upgrade correctly to Jessie which seems to have worked but with some problems.

- The WIFI allows me to connect to the network but there is no internet
  access.
- Do not get tethering/USB storing options when connect an Android
  phone to the system

```
iwconfig
wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"Home Network"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.437 GHz  Access Point: A0:F3:C1:37:B4:7C   
          Bit Rate=90 Mb/s   Tx-Power=16 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=70/70  Signal level=-40 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:95   Missed beacon:0

lo        no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:ca:3a:d4:7b:5c  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

eth0:avahi Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:ca:3a:d4:7b:5c  
          inet addr:169.254.8.115  Bcast:169.254.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:41 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:41 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:4017 (3.9 KiB)  TX bytes:4017 (3.9 KiB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 68:17:29:a4:8c:74  
          inet addr:192.168.1.103  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::6a17:29ff:fea4:8c74/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:250 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:131 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:73804 (72.0 KiB)  TX bytes:18910 (18.4 KiB)
```

and [Apt Cache Policy](http://paste.debian.net/180862/).

This was all working smooth in Wheezy and I can not figure out where the problem is.

Comment: Is your network configured via /etc/network/interfaces, NetworkManager, or something else? Also, could you use apt-show-versions (or whatever) to confirm you're actually running Jessie versions of everything? Finally, if possible, I suggest trying a [Debian Live disc](https://www.debian.org/CD/live/), to see if its something weird about your unplanned upgrade vs. a bug in Jessie.

Comment: I would also check if you can `ping -c2 4.2.2.2` and `ping -c2 google.com`, and `cat /etc/resolv.conf`.

Comment: @derobert I am using the default Network Manager of Jessie to choose,turn on/off the network.I ran a version check which shows me "8.0" which is Debian Jessie.I should not try Live Disc as it would be a new installation?Upgrading from Wheezy has restored many things for me like Virtual Box etc and I might loose them that way?Im not sure..

Comment: @Braiam I tried pinging external IP's and I get Destination Host Unreachable.Same is the case when I try to ping my Default Gateway.Internet works fine when I used Wired LAN connection but behaves weird when I attempt to use WIFI.

Comment: @techie_28 A live disc won't reinstall your machine as long as you don't run the installer. And you need to check more than /etc/debian_version—you might still have a mix of wheezy and jessie, or worse depending on what used to be in your sources.list.

Comment: @derobert /etc/debian_version gives me permission denied..How can I determine if Im still having mix of wheezy and Jessie.. you are right that happened when I updated to Jessie unknowingly as I had "stable" in my sources.list file.

Comment: @techie_28 OK, if it was just from having "stable" instead of "wheezy" in the sources.list, you shouldn't have a weird mix of versions. The permission denied is because that's a text file—look at it with `less` or even `cat`, don't try to run it. `apt-show-versions` will tell you which release each package comes from. But I think you're fine on that front as long as you're not showing any upgradeable or obsolete packages. And followed stuff in the release notes about, e.g., cleaning up old config files.

Comment: @derobert I had Wheezy and Stable both at that time I ran the update.. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found answer from **jm_** on **irc.debian.org**

commented out **allow-hotplug eth0** from the The primary network interface
in the file **/etc/network/interfaces**.

**eth0** was occupying the default gateway which was not getting free for WIFI.(detected this by using command **ifconfig eth0 down**).

thanks to all again.

Comment: I was confused coz I do not remembering doing anything on Debian Wheezy.It worked as plug an play i.e whenever WIFI was turned off I could use the LAN cable for internet without changing in any file.